# Trying to access array offset on value of type null in and Undefined array key how to fix

Tags: php, html, sqlite

I am a newbie to PHP and HTML. I use database from sqlite. I am running to this problem. The display question are now alright but the score page have these error

**Warning**: Trying to access array offset on value of type null in **C:\Users\ADMIN\OneDrive\Desktop\webprog\lab10\2\index.php** on line **95**

**Warning**: Undefined array key "questionIndex" in **C:\Users\ADMIN\OneDrive\Desktop\webprog\lab10\2\index.php** on line **103**

this is my php part code

```
<?php
session_start();

class MyDB extends SQLite3
{
    function __construct()
    {
        $this->open('questions.db');
    }
}

// 2. Open Database 
$db = new MyDB();
if (!$db) {
    echo $db->lastErrorMsg();
}

// Check if questions are set in session
if (!isset($_SESSION['questions'])) {
    // Fetch questions
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM questions";
    $result = $db->query($sql);

    // Store questions in session
    $_SESSION['questions'] = [];
    while ($row = $result->fetchArray(SQLITE3_ASSOC)) {
        $_SESSION['questions'][] = $row;
    }

    $_SESSION['score'] = 0;
    $_SESSION['questionIndex'] = 0;
}

// Display current question
$questions = $_SESSION['questions'];
$questionIndex = $_SESSION['questionIndex'];
$currentQuestion = (!empty($questions) && $questionIndex < count($questions)) ? $questions[$questionIndex] : null;

if ($currentQuestion !== null) {
    echo "<h1>" . $currentQuestion['QID'] . ")" . " " . $currentQuestion['Stem'] . "</h1>" . "<br> ";
    echo "<form method='post'>";
    echo "<input type='radio' name='answer' value='A'>" . $currentQuestion['Alt_A'] . "<br>";
    echo "<input type='radio' name='answer' value='B'>" . $currentQuestion['Alt_B'] . "<br>";
    echo "<input type='radio' name='answer' value='C'>" . $currentQuestion['Alt_C'] . "<br>";
    echo "<input type='radio' name='answer' value='D'>" . $currentQuestion['Alt_D'] . "<br>";
    echo "<button type='submit' name='submit'>Submit</button>";
    echo "</form>";
} else {
    // All questions are complete
    echo "<h2>Your Score: " . $_SESSION['score'] . "</h2>";
    // Reset session variables
    unset($_SESSION["questions"]);
    unset($_SESSION['score']);
    unset($_SESSION['questionIndex']);
}

// 3. Close Database
$db->close();

if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] === 'POST' && isset($_POST['submit'])) {
    // Check if the answer is correct
    $userAnswer = isset($_POST['answer']) ? $_POST['answer'] : '';
    $correctAnswer = $currentQuestion['Correct'];

    if ($userAnswer == $correctAnswer) {
        // Increase score
        $_SESSION['score']++;
    }

    // Move to the next question
    $_SESSION['questionIndex']++;
    // Fetch the next question
    $questionIndex = $_SESSION['questionIndex'];
    $currentQuestion = (!empty($questions) && $questionIndex < count($questions)) ? $questions[$questionIndex] : null;
}
?>
```

please tell me how to fix it.

Thank you very much.

Comment: Which are lines 95 and 103? The script you posted only has 76 lines.

Comment: When `$currentQuestion` is `null`, you unset the session variables. In this case you'll get the first error trying to access `$currentQuestion['Correct']`, and the second error from `$_SESSION['score']++;`. You need to skip all that code when the session variables aren't set.

Comment: line 95 is
    $correctAnswer = $currentQuestion['Correct'];
and line 103 is
$_SESSION['questionIndex']++;

Comment: Did you understand my second comment? You need to handle these error cases better.